# Do I need to drop Foreign Key constraints before adding a Unique Index on my Table

Tags: sql-server

Generated a script for adding a Unique NonClustered Index using SQL Server Management Studio (v17.2)'s "Generate Change Script" from the Design view of a table.

I noticed that the script that was generated dropped the FK's on the table prior to adding the index, and then re-added them.

Why is this a good idea?  I wouldn't have thought the FK's would have any impact to adding / removing indexes.

Comment: Just because SSMS generates that script doesn't mean it's best to do so. You can try to comment out the parts of the code dealing with the foreign key and see if it's still creating the new index.

Comment: It definitely still creates it... but that's not my question.

Comment: I'm no expert but I know [using table designers is considered as bad practice for a long time....](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers)

Comment: probably the answer then is: no.  :)

Comment: As I said I'm not an expert. You should probably wait for someone more knowledgeable then me to answer your question.